# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cache' not found in \prestashop\classes\ObjectModel.php on line 2000 1.7

Tags: php, caching, fatal-error, prestashop-1.7

I am working with prestashop 1.7
i deleleted the cache folder but i restored it, and i have the same problem
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Cache' not found in \prestashop\classes\ObjectModel.php on line 2000
idon't have the "class_index.php" file in cache folder. I don't have Cache.php in classes folder
any suggestion please

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are missing some core file,
yhe same thing happened to me in the past, when transferring with rsync the site from one server to another I excluded "cache" thinking to bypass the only cache folder, but I also excluded some core files :)

Check for the existance of the **/classes/cache** folder,
it should contain "Cache.php" and some other Cache related classes aswell.

If they are missing, restore them from a backup or from the official Prestashop archive of the same version.

Comment: thank you for your answer
i restored the cache folder but the problem remains

Answer (score 0):

i have these warning
Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" in /home/vrqlcrq/www/src/Core/Localization/CLDR/Reader.php on line 152

Warning: simplexml_load_file(): I/O warning : failed to load external entity "" in /home/vrqlcrq/www/src/Core/Localization/CLDR/Reader.php on line 162

Notice: Trying to get property 'parentLocales' of non-object in /home/vrqlcrq/www/src/Core/Localization/CLDR/Reader.php on line 212

Notice: Trying to get property 'parentLocale' of non-object in /home/vrqlcrq/www/src/Core/Localization/CLDR/Reader.php on line 212

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vrqlcrq/www/src/Core/Localization/CLDR/Reader.php on line 212

Notice: Trying to get property 'parentLocales' of non-object in /home/vrqlcrq/www/src/Core/Localization/CLDR/Reader.php on line 212

Notice: Trying to get property 'parentLocale' of non-object in /home/vrqlcrq/www/src/Core/Localization/CLDR/Reader.php on line 212

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/vrqlcrq/www/src/Core/Localization/CLDR/Reader.php on line 212